# .htaccess for cakephp

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, apache2

I'm trying to get a CakePHP application to work. For this, I've set up a brand new Debian installation, updated the configuration and put everything in /var/www, which has the following content:

```
app
cake
.htaccess
index.php
vendors
```

The .htaccess file contains the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    /webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) /webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

If I access my virtualhost (http://myhost/) I see the correct page. But even the JavaScript loaded with `src="/js/validate.js"` fails (it's located within `/var/www/app/webroot/js/validate.js`):

```
[Wed Aug 26 15:45:12 2009] [error] [client 10.7.10.52] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Wed Aug 26 15:45:12 2009] [debug] core.c(3063): [client 10.7.10.52] r->uri = /webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/js/prototype.js
[Wed Aug 26 15:45:12 2009] [debug] core.c(3069): [client 10.7.10.52] redirected from r->uri = /webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/js/prototype.js
[Wed Aug 26 15:45:12 2009] [debug] core.c(3069): [client 10.7.10.52] redirected from r->uri = /webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/js/prototype.js
[Wed Aug 26 15:45:12 2009] [debug] core.c(3069): [client 10.7.10.52] redirected from r->uri = /webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/js/prototype.js
[Wed Aug 26 15:45:12 2009] [debug] core.c(3069): [client 10.7.10.52] redirected from r->uri = /webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/js/prototype.js
[Wed Aug 26 15:45:12 2009] [debug] core.c(3069): [client 10.7.10.52] redirected from r->uri = /webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/js/prototype.js
[Wed Aug 26 15:45:12 2009] [debug] core.c(3069): [client 10.7.10.52] redirected from r->uri = /webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/js/prototype.js
[Wed Aug 26 15:45:12 2009] [debug] core.c(3069): [client 10.7.10.52] redirected from r->uri = /webroot/webroot/webroot/js/prototype.js
[Wed Aug 26 15:45:12 2009] [debug] core.c(3069): [client 10.7.10.52] redirected from r->uri = /webroot/webroot/js/prototype.js
[Wed Aug 26 15:45:12 2009] [debug] core.c(3069): [client 10.7.10.52] redirected from r->uri = /webroot/js/prototype.js
[Wed Aug 26 15:45:12 2009] [debug] core.c(3069): [client 10.7.10.52] redirected from r->uri = /js/prototype.js
[Wed Aug 26 15:45:12 2009] [debug] mod_deflate.c(632): [client 10.7.10.52] Zlib: Compressed 649 to 405 : URL /webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/js/prototype.js
```

Hence my **question**: what is the correct .htaccess required for CakePHP?

Many, many thanks!

Comment: Which directory do you have for the site root in your apache config? It should be /var/www/app/webroot - that may fix your problem.

Comment: @inkedmn: thank you, it would be /var/www - but the error was because I was using just one .htaccess, not 3, as I just found out. Thank you!

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The answer is that there are 3 different .htaccess files:

**/var/www/app/webroot/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

**/var/www/app/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

**/var/www/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

It's been my fault, everything is listed on the  [CakePHP site](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html). Thanks to everyone!

Comment: After finding my logfiles and googling the errors you listed above I found this! Thanks very much!

Comment: how to use this method in cakephp3 because there are no app folder in cakephp 3 please help me..

Comment: Images are not loading and links are not opening but index page running. Plz Help@MrG

Answer (score 3):

The correct .htaccess is the default:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
  RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

You have to add this in "/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default":

```
<Directory /var/www>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  allow from all
</Directory>
```

if section already exists change AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All

Answer (score 0):

Removing .htaccess from main file may solve this problem. It worked for me(need not remove from webroot)

Answer (score 0):

If allowed by your provider you may put all in the httpd.conf file as follow

```
<Directory /var/www>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  allow from all
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
      RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
  </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

And so on for others directories...

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP has only one `.htaccess` file inside webroot directory. No need more `.htaccess` files. You must set `app/webroot` as your `DOCUMENT_ROOT`.