# htaccess for cakephp

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.htaccess for cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334746/htaccess-for-cakephp)

I use this code for htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Inside this folder,

```
root/
app/
app/webroot
```

But not work

My live path is http://www.jacksonwebservices.co.uk/

Comment: What specifically do you want it to do? And what is it doing currently? Your question is a little vague.

Comment: We need way more details to be able to answer that.

Answer (score 2):

you should be running with the default cake supplied .htaccess files. there is nothing wrong with them for the most part. it seems like the .htaccess files are not readable by the webserver.

check your logs for more info.

Comment: The only one you might need to change would be the one in the document root (to add compression, handle www etc).

Comment: yes, but he just wants the site working for now... basics first

Answer (score 1):

Do you have that same .htaccess file in each of those directories? You need a different one in each of them. See http://book.cakephp.org/#!/view/917/Apache-and-mod_rewrite-and-htaccess for details.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: DO AS JUHANA SAYS: Make sure you have the correct htaccess files in the correct locations. They *are* all different. If it is as you describe, webroot is redirecting to itself redirecting to itself redirecting ...

Does your website have mod_rewrite enabled?

Create a file that contains just this:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

and save it as `phpinfo.php` in your document root (`public_html`, `www` or whatever)

Navigate to that page (http://www.jacksonwebservices.co.uk/phpinfo.php) and search the page for 'rewrite'. If you can't find it it's not enabled and CakePHP will not work in the default mode. See the manual for alternatives: http://book.cakephp.org/view/917/Apache-and-mod_rewrite-and-htaccess

You may need to contact your hosting to get it enabled or to find out how to do it yourself.

Comment: if mod_rewrite was not enabled the default / route would show with no css / images. other url's would show apache 404 errors

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right. If he has that .htaccess in webroot he'll get a 500 - it's looping. So he must have rewrite working.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are having the same Rewrite base problem that I recently had, put this in your .htaccess instead:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Sometimes it doesn't work without the 'RewriteBase' line at the top.