# .htaccess is not working by my desires with CakePHP

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, routes

There is /localhost/domains/localhost/myCakephpApp on web server. I can't do anything with folder structure, but I can edit .htaccess in /localhost/, which now simplified looks like this:

```
RewriteRule (.*) /domains/localhost/$1 [L]
```

My website in localhost/domains/localhost/myCakephpApp has standard cake .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
```

It is nice that http://localhost/whatever/ works, but all links in cakephp (done with html helper) are pointing to http://localhost/domains/localhost/whatever/ and it is accessible.

What should I do to make the website running only on http://localhost/ and not on http://localhost/domains/localhost/?

EDIT:

Okay, I have modified the .htaccess in root (http://localhost/):

```
RewriteRule ^$ /domains/localhost/app/webroot/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) /domains/localhost/app/webroot/$1 [L]
```

and deleted one in http://localhost/domains/localhost/ which means that the web is only accessible from http://localhost, but links are still pointing at http://localhost/domains/localhost/whatever (e404)

Is there something in cake's routing like "base url"? I have searched a lot, but nothing worked.

Comment: old coffee my friend http://stackoverflow.com/a/1334868/330658

Comment: @endo.anaconda No, That's not my problem at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that CakePHP uses the original uri from the server to resolve the action, not the rewritten one!

Try this "hack" in bootstrap.php:

```
Configure::write('App.base', '/');
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = preg_replace('|/domains/localhost|', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Comment: I now use simply `Configure::write('App.base', ''));`, that made the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could add a redirecting route:

```
Router::redirect('/domains/myDomainName.com/*', '/');
```

If you want to completely disable the route you can redirect to a 404 page. Something like that should work:

```
Router::redirect('/domains/myDomainName.com/*', array('controller'=>'pages', 'action'=>'error-404'), array('status' => '404'));
```

plus adding a 404-page in /View/Pages/error-404.ctp.