# Setting up baseurl in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I am really new to `CAKEPhP` so need some assistance. I used to work in `Codeigniter` before where i used to set the `base_url` and it set up all the paths. Recently i downloaded a website that is made in `cakephp`. Placed it in folder in `htdocs` named as `abc`. Configured all the database stuff. Now when i try run it on `localhost`, it seems that everything is pointing to the root folder. Here is the snapshot of the missing file errors i receive in console.

[image]

Any idea where i can set the `base_url` thing in `cakephp` so that it can start pointing to right folder?

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots with code / errors. Add them as text to your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [base\_url in CakePHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298552/base-url-in-cakephp)

Comment: @Abhishek: my question is that in which file do i set this base url?

Comment: check question itself, that already answer your query

Comment: can you pls show what you have tried? if you are completely clueless at this moment.. you may want to try changing .htaccess in localhost such that it redirects to folder abc http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404892/htaccess-is-not-working-by-my-desires-with-cakephp

Comment: please drop your images in img folder of cakephp. Path is App/webroot/img. and use the following syntax $this->Html->image('imagename.png');

Comment: It would also help to not use localhost, but a proper [vhost setup](http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/05/29/working-with-domains-locally/) locally.

Answer (score 0):

App.imageBaseUrl
Web path to the public images directory under webroot. If you are using a CDN you should set this value to the CDN’s location.

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html#bootstrapping-cakephp