# Cakephp 2.2 without mod_rewrite redirecting wrong

Tags: cakephp, mod-rewrite, cakephp-2.2

I did all the settings to not use mod_rewrite Apache 2.2 and CakePHP.

Apache2 is up and running and Cake seems to be running too. If I go `http://127.0.0.1/cake/index.php`, all green tags along (using PostgreSQL 9.1). I followed the tutorial to [create the blog project](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html) and created the controller file at `/var/www/cake/app/Controller/PostsController.php` (also has `CakeController` and `AppController` and `PagesController` files).

In the Model dir I got Post.php and AppModel, as the tutorial said. And in the View folder, I created Posts folder and the files index.ctp and view.ctp.

When I type an url like `http://127.0.0.1/cake/index.php?url=/posts/` it goes to index.php of the Cake main folder. It redirects to there! If I change the URL for example to `http://127.0.0.1/cake/index.php?url=/posts/view/1` (like the tutorial) same thing. What went wrong in this picture?

My environment is Debian 6.0-6 64bits. Apache2.2 (installed with SO), CakePHP 2.2.3 and PHP 5.2.8 (or higher).

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that `mod_rewrite` is on and rewriting?
Can you post the contents of your .htaccess files - the one in the top level dir (i.e. htdocs) and the one in your `app/webroot` dir? Your top-level dir is the one with `app` and `lib` in it.
I suspect your `RewriteRule`'s are wrong in both. Anyway if you haven't changed those files it will definately be wrong. :) You shouldn't change the *middle* `.htaccess` file - the one in `app`.

This is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334746/htaccess-for-cakephp) and the CakeBook explains it [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html#apache-and-mod-rewrite-and-htaccess). But I personally use a bit different set-up:

**/var/www/test.cake.lan/htdocs/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ /app/webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) /app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**/var/www/test.cake.lan/htdocs/app/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

**/var/www/test.cake.lan/htdocs/app/webroot/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/webroot/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Dude, ty VM for yr answer but i think u missread... As i said my goal is NOT use mod_rewrite. So as explained i uncomment a line and delete all .htaccesss (actually i renamed all, but) and i used url´s  as mentioned b4.

Comment: Anyways, i appeciatte the answer... Yr links led me to learn more.