# Cakephp3 strato installation

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, url-rewriting

i want to write a little Cakephp3 application for a friend. Now i developed a part of the application locally and i want to install this on his server. He got a managed server at strato.de. I have no access to a shell or something like this to configure everything by myself.

**What i did already to solve the problem:**

- I googled around and found several things about some definitions in the htaccess-files: [.htaccess for cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334746/htaccess-for-cakephp) but it didn't solve my problem.
- I also read the installation-guide of cakephp.

**The problem:**

I can't access the application. If i try to open the url i only get a complete white page. So what do i have to do to access the application?

Thanks for help!

Comment: completely white page -> read the error log. If you have no access to the server to do that, you need to ask someone who does.

Comment: The idea was good! :) I didn't where to look at for the log files but i found them... the reason for that "error" is that the hoster doesn't support the php_intl.ext extension... that's why there was a white page. Thank's vor that hint!

Answer (score 0):

Put this lines in you root index.php file to show all errors

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", "on");
```

(overhead this line)

```
require 'webroot' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'index.php';
```

But I imagine a message like this...

> *Fatal error: **You must enable the intl extension** to use CakePHP in ... cakephp/config/bootstrap.php on line 38*

I talked with Strato about it, but they didn't give me any solution for shared hostings...

If it's any info, I checked hostings strato and its support laravel5