# How to config Cakephp3 to shared server?

Tags: cakephp, server, hosting, cakephp-3.0, web-hosting

I am struggle to upload my cakephp 3 project to shared hosting. My host is Hostgator. Things I have doneL
- Download the project from Git then extract every folder ( src, bin, webroot, etc..) under /home/username/public_html/.
- Have changed PHP to version 5.6 in the server.
- Have created database in the server and change the config/app.php

The website still not up. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32218957/cakephp3-strato-installation/37110447#37110447) sounds **intl** extension

Comment: Man Hostgator said they dont support INTL indeed. Thanks for your help, I will change host I guess.

Comment: Have you ran Composer in your project directory after you downloaded the repo?