# while using cakePHP framework, but still want to write customised .htaccess for RewriteRule

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, cakephp, url-rewriting

I'm using CakePhp but I still need to use .htaccess to make special rules for my site's RewriteRule. Ex: if request is with certain filetype (png), then rewrite to certain URL.

Could you help me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Cake PHP shouldn't stop you from adding `redirect rules` to your `.htaccess` file.

Check out this similar question for some inspiration.  [.htaccess for cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334746/htaccess-for-cakephp)