# unable to load php from interface folder

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I am new to Apache and recently my developer passed me the website with htaccess to host on Apache 2.4 running on CentOS 7, the website is running on the Windows laptop but not on the server with the same htaccess.

The webpage works like this, when user hits the url at http://www.example.com, and click on the links, it will load the rest of the files from a folder called interface.

The original htaccess as follow:

```
RewriteEngine On

#this is for specific users
RewriteBase /v1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /v1/index.php?m=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /v1/error.php?=error
```

However it only load the main page, and the rest will load as follow:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /example was not found on this server.
```

I have tried the recommendations on this page [Generic htaccess redirect www to non-www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www)

and this page [.htaccess for cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334746/htaccess-for-cakephp)

and this page [Remove .php extension with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess/4027458#4027458)

however all of them not working as what we want.

Any way I can get it to work?

Comment: You say its interface folder, but in your htaccess i see v1 folder. Can you explain?

Comment: I am not sure what happened, after i renamed the root folder, things are working now, thanks.